# Volley Post method for json object

Tags: android, post, android-volley, json

```
data={
    "request": {
       "type": "event_and_offer",
       "devicetype": "A"
    },
    "requestinfo": {
       "value": "offer"
      }
}
```

how to post this request from volley plz help

```
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,url, null   ,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {




                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }) {

        /**
         * Passing some request headers
         * */
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return headers;
        }
```

js is reffer to my jsson object ...... i make my jsson like this.....

```
JSONObject jsonobject_one = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonobject_one.put("type", "event_and_offer");
        jsonobject_one.put("devicetype", "I");

        JSONObject jsonobject_TWO = new JSONObject();
        jsonobject_TWO.put("value", "event");
        jsonobject = new JSONObject();

        jsonobject.put("requestinfo", jsonobject_TWO);
        jsonobject.put("request", jsonobject_one);

        js = new JSONObject();
        js.put("data", jsonobject.toString());
        Log.e("created jsson", "" + js);
```

But it Not response the value what to do plzz help

Answer (score 22, accepted):

first your json data:

```
JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
try {
    JSONObject jsonobject_one = new JSONObject();

    jsonobject_one.put("type", "event_and_offer");
    jsonobject_one.put("devicetype", "I");

    JSONObject jsonobject_TWO = new JSONObject();
    jsonobject_TWO.put("value", "event");
    JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject();

    jsonobject.put("requestinfo", jsonobject_TWO);
    jsonobject.put("request", jsonobject_one);


    js.put("data", jsonobject.toString());

}catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

then your json request:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.POST,url, js,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        }) {

    /**
     * Passing some request headers
     * */
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
         HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
         headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return headers;
    }
```

Notice the **header**

and if you want to test in localhost use below code and set your url to connect your localhost server and ip address:
below code put all of your request in a text file, i tried it and it works

```
<?php
file_put_contents('test.txt', file_get_contents('php://input'));
?>
```

Comment: Why is it required to send `charset=utf-8`  and not just `'application/json'`