# How can i send string array through volley?

Tags: android, gson, android-volley

I have to send a json like this:

```
{
    "user_id": "5750891ffe77d2d41732d535",
    "categories" :["5751cd8cb61c39200b368cf3","575b35b9c456c8751cd8530f", "575b35c5c456c8751cd85313"]
}
```

but volley only send strings, not an array. This is my request class, i'm using the volley StringRequest but i think there is a way to send also an array:

```
public class VolleyRequest extends StringRequest {

    private Map<String, String> params;
    Context context;

    public VolleyRequest(int method, final Context context, String url, Map<String, String> params, final Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(method, url, listener, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Log.d("WS", volleyError.toString());
            }
        });

       setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 10, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));    

       this.params = params;
       this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        return this.params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Volley Post method for json object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906689/volley-post-method-for-json-object)

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out! you have to override the getBody() function, create a custom encodeParameters function and also override getBodyContentType() changing it to return "application/json".

```
public class VolleyRequest extends StringRequest {

    private Map<String, String> params;
    Context context;

    public VolleyRequest(int method, final Context context, String url, String json, final Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(method, url, listener, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Log.d("WS", volleyError.toString());
            }
        });

       setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 10, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));    

       this.params = params;
       this.context = context;
    }

  @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        return encodeParameters(getParamsEncoding());
    }

    private byte[] encodeParameters(String paramsEncoding) {
        try {
            if(json!=null) {
                return json.getBytes(paramsEncoding);
            }
            else return  null;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + paramsEncoding, uee);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/json";
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        return this.params;
    }
}
```

Look that now i pass a String json as parameter on my request, not a HashMap. To create that string a used Gson and a Model of my wanted json body:

```
public class ModelSendFilters {
    String user_id;
    String[] categories;

    public String getUser_id() {return user_id;}
    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {this.user_id = user_id;}

    public String[] getCategories() {return categories;}
    public void setCategories(String[] categories) {this.categories = categories;}

}
```

To create the String json:

```
new Gson().toJson(user, ModelSendFilters.class)
```

Comment: There are many posts here about POST-ing a JSON string that don't involve the Java model